# Online FPGA/HDL synthesizer

Tags: fpga, verilog, vhdl, xilinx

I recall seeing a web-based HDL synthesizer a couple years ago, but I can't find it anymore. I believe it was just a frontend that ran the vendors' synthesis tools on the server.

Does this sound familiar to anyone? I don't remember the name, and nothing is turning up in my searches. (Perhaps it got taken down?)

Comment: Was it any of the ones listed at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HDL_simulators#Online_simulators ? Just realised you said synthesizer but they might be of interest anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that company is still around. It is called Plunifiy. Please check out http://www.plunify.com

Comment: I have been using their service since the early days of their start. They have a pretty good setting with very reasonable pricing. It is also very useful to have access to all the tools while travelling.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check out:

[EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/home)